# Convert this String to datetime C#

Tags: c#

I tried converting this string to date time using ParseExact, but its giving exception on String format(String was not recognized as a valid DateTime)

Can someone please suggest some solution

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2016-11-29T13:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're parsing 24H time format. Use `HH` instead of `hh` for the hours.